# Communication problem between background script and content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I am trying to build an addon working on both firefox and chrome in order to get started with extensions (it's not an extension to be published). My aim is basically to recover the mouse movements and a screenshot of the tab and send them through a REST API.

Everything was working fine as of yesterday, but as I am testing today, I am getting an error stating that the content script isn't able to communicate with my background script.

I have checked if a new version of firefox was released overnight and it doesn't seem to be the case to my knowledge. I then have extensively checked the [google runtime APIs](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/runtime), and my code seems to be constructed accordingly to the documentation.
What's more intriguing is that everything was working fine even with multiple trials.

If I try to print the content of the sent message, it doesn't print anything.

When I load a temporary addon on firefox, I get a temporary ID, and the error I get is the following :

> Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.
>   background.js:1:745 Unchecked lastError value: Error: Could not
>   establish connection. Receiving end does not exist. background.js:1
>
> sendRequestToSpecificTab
>   moz-extension://94826cb7-3494-4f28-abda-e0dbb477ca37/js/background.js:1

I noticed that the ID specified in the error is different than the ID that is provided when I load the addon.

Here is my code :

keylog.js

```
//capturing the mouse movements
 window.addEventListener("mousemove", logMouseMove, false);
 window.addEventListener("mousedown", logMouseDown, false);

function logMouseMove(e) {
let currentdate = Date.now();
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({action: "mouselog",data : currentdate+':  ('+e.pageX+','+e.pageY+')'});
} 

function logMouseDown(e) {
let currentdate = Date.now();
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({action: "mouselog",data :currentdate+': ['+e.pageX+','+e.pageY+']'});
}
```

And background.js :

```
"use strict";

let concatenated = "";
let mouse_coord={};
let mouse_json = {};


var id = "";

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(msg => {
  var ID = function () {
    return '_' + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9);
  };

  if(msg.action == "mouselog") {
    let splitted = msg.data.split(':');
    mouse_coord[splitted[0]] = splitted[1];
    console.log(msg.data);
    if(splitted[1].charAt(0) === '[') {
      id = ID();
      mouse_json[id] = mouse_coord;
      mouse_coord = {};
      concatenated += JSON.stringify(mouse_json, null, 4);
      let donnes= {};
      donnes['id'] = id;
      donnes['data'] = mouse_json;
      chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow:true}, (tab) => {
        donnes['tab'] = tab;
        sendData('http://localhost:33333/mouselog', JSON.stringify(donnes));
      }); 

      mouse_json = {};
      chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(
        null,
        {},
        function(dataUrl)
        {
          let data = {};
          data['id'] = id;
          data["data"] = dataUrl;
          sendData('http://localhost:33333/saveimg', JSON.stringify(data));
          console.log('Sent screenshot');
        }
        );
      try {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
          file: 'injection_script.js'
        }, function() {
          if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
            message.innerText = 'There was an error injecting script : \n' + chrome.runtime.lastError.message;
          }
        });
      } catch(err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    }       
  }
});
```

I am also declaring on my manifest all the necessary permissions : 
"all_urls", "activeTab", "storage", "tabs", "webRequest"

Is there anything I am doing wrong ? I haven't changed a single line to the code that was working last time I tested, so I am doubting the issue may not be from my code, but from the browser ?

Comment: It could be a bug in the browser in which case you can find when it broke using [mozregression](https://mozilla.github.io/mozregression/).

Comment: I just executed mozregression and it led me to the conlusion that the browser isn't the problem. I found the mistake by opening my file in binary mode in vim, and I had some hidden characters in my content script, thus, the error wasn't displayed in the console...